# VB.NET Graph API example with OWIN and Azure

Tags: vb.net, azure, single-sign-on, owin

I have my asp.net webforms site authenticating with Azure but I wondered how I can integrate the Graph api so that I can read more of the user profile. Here is my startup - can anyone provide sample code that would allow me for example, to read the users manager from Azure?

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin
Imports System.IdentityModel.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        Dim appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        Dim authority = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = appId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(context)
                                                 Dim username As String = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value
                                                 Dim authTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), True, "")
                                                 Dim encryptedTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket)
                                                 context.Response.Cookies.Append(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
                                                 Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                             End Function,
                .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                            context.HandleResponse()
                                            context.Response.Write(context.Exception.Message)
                                            Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                        End Function
            }
        })
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am afraid you won't find any sample in vb.net nowadays. You'd better use c# or perform write the vb.net code on top of the REST Api

Comment: Microsoft does not provide any graph API samples with VB. You can refer to the C# sample(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp/tree/master/Demos/03-add-msgraph) to write your VB project

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Thiago Custodio said in the comment, there are no samples in vb.net nowadays. Take a look at this [c# sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp/tree/master/Demos/03-add-msgraph). Or you can write the vb.net code on top of [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).